# Paraview looping with SaveScreenshot in a server is very slow

Tags: ssh, screenshot, paraview

I mean to get a series of snapshots, at a sequence of time steps, of a layout with two views (one RenderView + one LineChartView).
For this I put together a script, see below.

I do

```
ssh -X myserver
```

and there I run

```
~/ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/pvbatch myscript.py
```

The script is extremely slow to run. I conceive the following reasons/bottlenecks:

1. Communication of the graphic part (`ssh -X`) from the remote server to my computer.
2. Display of graphics in my computer.
3. Processing in the server.

**Is there a way to assess which is the bottleneck, with my current resources?**
(For instance, I know I could get a faster communication to assess item 1, but I cannot do that now.)

**Is there a way to accelerate `pvbatch`?**

The answer likely depends on my system, but perhaps there are generic actions I can take.

```
Creation of the layout with two views
...

ans = GetAnimationScene()
time_steps = ans.TimeKeeper.TimestepValues
for istep in range(len(time_steps)) :
    tstep = time_steps[istep]
    ans.AnimationTime = tstep
    fname = "combo" + '-' + '{:08d}'.format(istep) + '.png'
    print( "Exporting image " + fname + " for time step " + str(tstep) )
    SaveScreenshot(fname, viewLayout1, quality=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the -X ?

Just set DISPLAY to :0 and do not forward graphics.

Comment: Do you think this will accelerate the script? I will post feedback as soon as I can test this.

Comment: Probably, and if it does not, you will have a cleaner workflow anyway and removed one of your potential problem.

Comment: I didn't have the chance to test it (things get in the way...). I think it might be misleading if I accept it without at least trying something. Will do!

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is most likely the rendering on your local display. If your server has a X server, you can perform the rendering on your server by setting accordingly the DISPLAY environnement variable as Mathieu explained.

If your server does not have a X server running, then the best option is to build Paraview on your server using either the OSMesa backend or the EGL backend (if you have a compatible graphic card on it).